# ROS rviz OGRE EXCEPTION

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Operating System Details:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) - ROS Hydro

The following command:

> rosrun rviz rviz

Briefly displays the rviz logo, before repeating the following error 100 times:

> [ WARN] [1383004708.902971662]: OGRE EXCEPTION(3:RenderingAPIException): Invalid parentWindowHandle (wrong server or screen) in GLXWindow::create at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.4/RenderSystems/GL/src/GLX/OgreGLXWindow.cpp (line 229)

> rviz::RenderSystem: error creating render window: std::exception

And then finally giving up with the following messages:

> [ERROR] [1383004708.903200106]: Unable to create the rendering window after 100 tries.

> rviz: /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-rviz-1.10.9-0precise-20131021-0017/src/rviz/ogre_helpers/render_system.cpp:374: Ogre::RenderWindow* rviz::RenderSystem::makeRenderWindow(intptr_t, unsigned int, unsigned int): Assertion `false' failed.

> Aborted (core dumped)

I've tried re-installing rviz, which didn't help. Also, I was having the same problem before moving from fuerte to hydro (though a long while back rviz was working fine with fuerte). I suspect it has been an update to rviz or ogre which has caused this problem, but I'm not really sure how to go about attempting to repair it..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/95256/ros-rviz-ogre-exception/) by [Stephen Vidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3606/stephen-vidas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-10-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) on 2013-10-29**:
Try 'sudo  apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-current'

**Comment by [Tim Murphy](https://answers.ros.org/users/6187/tim-murphy/) on 2014-04-08**:
I have them same error and dgossow's suggestion didn't work. Any other ideas?

**Comment by [bwillaert](https://answers.ros.org/users/12931/bwillaert/) on 2014-07-29**:
Same problem here with 12.04 and Hydro and the following hardware:

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1587
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidia_331_updates, nvidia_304_updates, nouveau, nvidiafb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't look like I am able to answer my own question, but I managed to get around the problem:

I changed my graphics drivers according to post #16 on the following link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2088918&page=2&s=1ad177380f5de29c7c0cae5675a7da52

My suspicion is that there is some incompatibility between Ogre3D and the nvidia proprietry drivers, so its best to avoid them.

---

Originally posted by [Stephen Vidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3606/stephen-vidas/) with karma: 131 on 2013-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0